# How do I identify the element by the class with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

````html
<input class="inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To" name="password" type="password" placeholder="" aria-label="Password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="999" spellcheck="false" value="">```
````

^this is the HTML
ive been trying something like

```py
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To']/div/input").click()
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To']")
```

Comment: `_djjkz` and `cIJ7To` are dynamic values and would change on each new session.

Comment: Ok so you can get it with the name "password" in that case driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")

Answer (score 0):

To identify the clickable element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password'][aria-label='Password']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password' and @aria-label='Password']")
  ```

---

Ideally, to identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password'][aria-label='Password']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password' and @aria-label='Password']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```